# Extjs - textarea enter event

Tags: extjs, extjs4, textarea

I'm using textarea and I can't enter to break line.

```
        xtype: 'textarea',
        name:'mt',
        fieldLabel: 'example',
        labelWidth: 100,
        width:100,
        labelAlign : 'right',
        maxLength: 100,
        value: 'example'
```

I'm using the code belowwith above and it's working and store data into mysql with type varchar(500..), but when I re-load it to the same form (textarea) it's not running.

```
             listeners: { 
                afterrender: function(){
                    var me = this;
                     me.el.swallowEvent(['keypress','keydown'    ]); 
                }
            }
```

The first: How can I fix that?

The second: I listen enter event at (all) form with below code, but I want it not listen in my textarea (because enter to break line), is it possible and how to do that? thanks

```
 ,listeners: {
    render : function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.util.KeyNav', this.getEl(), {
            "enter" : function(e){  
                // do form
            }
            scope: this       
        });
    }
  }
```

**Update first solution**
I using the code to re-load data from mysql to my form :) and it's working well

```
str_replace("\n", "\\n",$r[..])
```

I try to solve second problem. My idea is check if textarea focus = true then do not run (3rd code in my question) but i know set focus is this.down('textarea').focus(true,100); but i don't know how to check has focus?

**Update second solution**

```
enableKeyEvents: true,
listeners: { 
                afterrender: function(){
                    var me = this;
                     me.el.swallowEvent(['keypress','keydown'    ]); 
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout enableKeyEvents

true to enable the proxying of key events for the HTML input field.
Defaults to: false

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.form.field.TextArea-cfg-enableKeyEvents

Comment: i using  me.el.swallowEvent(['keypress','keydown'    ]); above and it's working (datas store in mysql are multi line but when i reload to form it's not working :(

Comment: I try to solve second problem. My idea is check if textarea focus = true then do not run (3rd code in my question) but i know set focus is this.down('textarea').focus(true,100); but i don't know how to check has focus?